# Adjusting point on a QLine, after its been drawn

Tags: c++, qt

So I am drawing a QLine based on the position of a QDial and I need to adjust the position of the points on the line periodically after it has been drawn in the scene.

Here is how I'm getting the points

```
void addNewPoint( int qdialAngle ){
    double oldX = m_sceneCenter;
    double oldY = m_sceneCenter;
    double newX = oldX + qCos(qDegreesToRadians(range)) * m_sceneRadius;
    double newY = oldY + qCos(qDegreesToRadians(range)) * m_sceneRadius;
    QPointF pt(newX, newY);
    m_historyPoint_list.append(pt);
    m_historyPoint_count++;

    switch(m_historyPoint_count){
        case 1:
            m_historyPoint_A = pt;
            break;
        case 2:
            m_historyPoint_B = pt;
            m_historyPoint_count = 0;
            break;
     }
}
```

And here is how I'm drawing the line from those points.

```
void drawPathLine(){
    m_HistoryLine = QLineF(m_historyPoint_A, m_historyPoint_B);
    QPen linePen(Qt::green, Qt::SolidLine);
    linePen.setWidth(2);

    m_currentLineItem = m_GraphicsScene->addLine(m_HisoryLine, linePen);
    m_line_list.append(m_currentLineItem);
}
```

This all works fine, I just don't know how to adjust the points on the line afterwards.

Basically, I need the line that gets drawn to be sucked into the center of the scene slowly over time.

If I scale the QGraphicsScene slowly upwards overtime, the effect works for the most part, it worked for the prototype at least, but the problem is that the line gets smaller and smaller as time progresses.  QLine doesn't seem to have a flag to set to ignoretransformations which would have worked in this case.  Either way, scaling the scene has other issues which leads me to believe that it probably isn't the way to go anyway.

I tried to make pointers of the Points, but QLineF didn't accept pointers.

How can adjust this line once it has been drawn?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
void offsetPoints(){ //called from a timer
    foreach(QGraphicsLineItem* line, m_line_list){
        QLineF adjLine = line->line();
        int adjLine_pt1_x = adjLine.p1.x();
        int adjLine_pt1_y = adjLine.p1.y();
        int adjLine_pt2_x = adjLine.p2.x();
        int adjLine_pt2_y = adjLine.p2.y();

        QPointF newOffsetP1 = QPointF(getNewPoint( getBearing(adjLine_pt1_x, adjLine_pt1_y),
        getRange(adjLine_pt1_x, adjLine_pt1_y));

        QPointF newOffsetP2 = QPointF(getNewPoint( getBearing(adjLine_pt2_x, adjLine_pt2_y),
        getRange(adjLine_pt2_x, adjLine_pt2_y));

        adjLine.setP1(newOffsetP1);
        adjLine.setP2(newOffsetP2);
        line->setline(adjLine);
    }
}

QPointF getNewPoint(double bearing, double range){
    double oldX = 400;
    double oldY = 400;

    double m_offsetSpeed -= 0.1;
    double newX = oldX + qCos(qDegreesToRadians(bearing)) * (range - m_offsetSpeed);         
    double newY = oldY + qSin(qDegreesToRadians(bearing)) * (range - m_offsetSpeed); 

    QPointF newPoint = QPointF(newX, newY);
    return newPoint;
}

double getBearing(int Xpos, int Ypos){
    double lat1 = m_center.x();
    double lon1 = m_center.y();
    double lat2 = Xpos;
    double lon2 = Ypos;

    double X = qSin(lon2 - lon1) * qCos(lat2);
    double Y = qCos(lat1) * qSin(lat2) - qSin(lat1) * qCos(lat2) * qCos(lon2 - lon1);
    double bearing = (qAtan2(Y,X) * (180 / 3.14159265), 360);

    if(bearing < 0)
        bearing += 360;

    return bearing;
}

double getRange(int Xpos, int Ypos){
    double centerX = m_center.x();
    double centerY = m_center.y();

    double newX = centerX - Xpos;
    double newY = centerY - Ypos;

    double distance = qPow(newX, 2) - qPow(newY,2);

    double range = qSqrt( distance);
    return range;
}
```

The lines definitely are doing something after they are drawn, but their behavior is very erratic. I feel like I'm close, maybe my math is off?

I'm storing the points used to create the lines in my "m_historyPoint_list". My thought was that I should be able to perform these calculations on the points and then the line will "simply" update, but they didn't work because once the points are in the list, they become const points.

Again, if anyone knows of a way that I could apply the ItemIgnoresTransformations to my lines so that as I scale my scene, the lines won't shrnk, most of this headache would go away.

Comment: The function addNewPoint is irreproducible since there are variables not defined besides that you never use qdialAngle

Comment: I'm having to transfer code form one computer to another in order to get this up here so yes, there are methods that are missing.

qdialAngle gets passed in directly from the angle set on the QDial. Whenever the QDial changes, it calls addNewPoint passing in the given angle.

m_offsetSpeed -= 0.1 as shown in the comment.

Same with m_scene_center, I show how it is being calculated (view->size().width()/2)


I show you the value of

Comment: You could share your code through github, dropbox, etc.

Comment: No I cannot. Job restriction.

Comment: Then share something reproducible

Comment: updated addNewPoint with the values that are being used.